# Accessing columns without name and deleting certain data from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe which has 14 columns and it does not have any headers in it. The first column is date and I need to delete all rows which is older than 25 months from now and does not contain any date.

```
                        44.93442    -79.37061   Tow 36  45.06541    -79.43384   R103    2053    WL7 CCG     
                        44.96092    -78.39428   Flatbed Tow 56  0   0   P201    3040    SHOP    CCG     
                        45.05056    -78.50632   Jump Start/Battery Test 30  45.12152    -78.61311   P201    1426    FB1 CCG     
                        45.15709    -77.91703   Winch/Extrication   20  0   0   K143    957 SHOP    CCG     
                        45.24038    -81.64227   Tow 36  45.25674    -81.65996   W444    1597    WL1 CCG     
                        45.32589    -78.98001   Winch/Extrication   79  0   0   R105    43  SHOP    CCG     
                        45.33402    -79.20586   Tow 38  45.32871    -79.21218   R103    226 WL10    CCG     
                        46.2062     -82.47623   Tow 68  46.18153    -82.96333   R812    588 FM1 CCG     
                        46.50164    -84.28004   Winch/Extrication   36  46.53398    -84.35199   R829    10  WL1 CCG     
                        46.50694    -84.32854   No service  27  46.53578    -84.38477   R829    124 WL1 CCG     
                        46.51246    -84.33669   No service  728 46.50897    -84.3295    R829    123 FB1 CCG     
                        46.52354    -84.38171   Flatbed Tow 66  46.51035    -84.25437   R829    49  FB2 CCG     
2017-11-11  00:03:10    43.68109    -79.53289   Tow 33  43.54982    -79.71832   C1  2   WL2 CCG     00:05:50
2017-11-11  00:04:09    43.91352    -78.9673    Tow 24  43.93242    -78.86989   C207    4   M255    CCG     00:04:11
2017-11-11  00:05:09    42.93152    -81.19933   Tow 161 42.91458    -81.2216    G72 5   FB6 CCG P5  00:16:21
2017-11-11  00:05:14    44.26861    -76.57645   Jump Start/Battery Test 21  44.26594    -76.49862   K112    6   LS1 CCG     00:12:23
2017-11-11  00:07:09    43.30024    -79.90106   Flatbed Tow 53  43.30506    -79.90795   H935    8   350 CCG P5  00:14:35
2017-11-11  00:07:14    43.71246    -79.55377   Tow 40  43.7081 -79.5536    C100    9   WL25    CCG P2  00:07:22
```

I have tried this so far but I did not get any success yet.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

#find the 25 month prior month from now 

N = 761
today = datetime.now()
lastMonth = today-timedelta(days=N)
month24= lastMonth.strftime("%Y-%m")
print (month24)
data = pd.read_csv("E:/ERS_DATA_TEMP.txt",delimiter='\t', dtype=str)

#access the dataframe and column

x=data.iloc[:,0]
print (x)
#remove data 
data.drop(data[data.iloc[:,0]],[np.NaN]>=month24)
y=len(data.index)
```

Comment: just pass `header=None` then convert `df[0]` to datetime and drop null rows and anything less than 24 months. not sure what delimiter your data is, but i can't easily read it into pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read in data without headers

`df = pd.read_csv("E:/ERS_DATA_TEMP.txt",delimiter='\t', dtype=str, header=None)`

Drop all rows without time

`df = df[df[0].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce').notnull()]`

Finally slice on dates

`df = df[df[0] > month24]`

Comment: glad I could help `+1`, feel free to ask any more questions you have

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iloc` accessor to operate on the column:

```
# convert month to days
n_days = 25 * 30

# both will return a boolean series
t1 = df.iloc[:,0].apply(lambda x: (x - pd.to_datetime('today')).days).gt(n_days)
t2 = df.iloc[0].isna()

# remove unwanted dates
df1 = df.loc[t1 & t2]
```

> **Sample Data**

```
period = pd.date_range(start='20130101', freq='M', periods=1000)
df = pd.DataFrame({'period': period})
```